How to share a GPU with LXC?
I have some GNOME wayland Linux installs in KVM using virt-manager with spicevmc on Debian 12 that are performant with default settings.
I added a LXC instance to virt-manager.
How can I get a spice, waypipe, or equally efficient low lag graphical connection to it?
gnome-shell --wayland
libmutter-Message: 16:55:07.467: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a Wa
yland display server
libmutter-Message: 16:55:07.480: Made thread 'KMS thread' realtime scheduled
Failed to setup: No GPUs found

Searching I found instructions mentioning /etc/pve/lxc/.conf but I don't have that, only /etc/libvirt/lxc.conf and /etc/libvirt/lxc/.xml
So how to share a GPU with LXC?
